# New to python coding, trying to make my own macro on my chromebook using a python package pyautogui; running the program nothing happens no error

Tags: python, pyautogui, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to code a macro for my Chromebook using the Linux Chromebook option in the settings(Linux development environment (Beta)).

I'm using a python Idle 3.7 to make this program and what I want the program to do is to open the application next to the chrome icon on my Chromebook taskbar. I've got the location of the application I want the program to open, when I run the program it doesn't open the application can anyone help troubleshoot this :D. I've also tried running the program on the Linux terminal but the same result.... The program does not produce a run time error it just stops and does not execute the pyautogui code.

Here are some screenshots of my program running in the Linux terminal and python IDLE:
https://ibb.co/DkTtyLN

Actual code:

```
import pyautogui
import time 

print("test")  

time.sleep(2)
#print(pyautogui.position())

pyautogui.click(1990, 2144)
```

Thank you in advance any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: The code works for me (with sensible coordinates). I can only suggest that your coordinates are wrong. In particular, 2144 seems huge for a Y coordinate.

Comment: This is my chromebooks width and height which i founded out with the size function that comes with pyautogui: Size(width=4285, height=2857) :( . Do you think its just chrome OS not allowing pyautogui so execute o.O?

Comment: I think you don't have a chromebook with a screen resolution of 4285 x 2857. That's 1.5x as many pixels as a 4K display.